# How can count all images on a page with JavaScript (including CSS and img)

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

It's trivial to get the `<img>` elements on a page with JavaScript:

- `document.images`
- `document.getElementsByTagName('img')`

But is there a (reasonably easy) way to get **all** images loaded on the page?

I've considered looping through all elements using `querySelectorAll('*')` and checking their `style.background` and `style.backgroundImage` properties for `url`, then combining that with the html image elements.

Is that approach my only choice? Will that catch everything? I imagine there are edge cases with images loaded by JavaScript, new HTML5 image elements (picture, ...).

I'm not yet sure how I want to handle data-uri images or SVG, but if an answer covered that, it'd probably be a good thing.

Comment: Some browser can have url for cursor property 
see http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-cursor-styles/.
SVG can have "image" element.

Comment: After some more thought/research, it appears that there is no *blanket* "get all images on the page" approach, and it is going to be just combining the aforementioned methods for finding the images in different ways depending on how they are included. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Made a new answer, this one will find all elements with a certian background, and can definitely be modified for all items that have a background or a couple different backgrounds.

Also you could modify for length of string, make sure it isn't an empty string and therefore has a background and then count that element.

*** JavaScript Solution ***

I would say going though all elements is your only choice by what you have stated.

```js
var count = 0;
window.onload = function () {
  var elems = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");  
  for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)
  {
      var properties = (elems[i].currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(elems[i], false));
      background = properties.backgroundImage.slice(4, -1);
      if(background.indexOf("http://placehold.it/50x50") > -1)
      {
         count++;
      }
  }
  alert(count);
};
```

```css
p {
  background: url('http://placehold.it/50x50');
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I think you have to search through all elements and for each one obtain its image, depending on the type of element.

Here's a functional code that will give you all images in a webpage inside IMG tags and also other common places (DIVs, Ps, etc). You can expand the search to other tags, or even to all tags. It won't search in SVG and other "*non-basic*" forms of placing images:

```
var imageSearch = 
{
    image_array: {},
    valid_image_nodes: ["DIV", "P", "SECTION", "SPAN"],

    scan_for_valid_images: function(node) 
    {
        if (node.nodeType === 1) 
        {
            if (node.nodeName === "IMG") {
                this.image_array[node.getAttribute("src")] = true;
            }
            else
            {
                if (this.valid_image_nodes.indexOf(node.nodeName) !== -1) {
                    div_style = node.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(node, false);
                    if (div_style.backgroundImage !== "none") {
                        url = div_style.backgroundImage;
                        this.image_array[url.slice(4, url.indexOf(')'))] = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        var children = node.childNodes;
        for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            this.scan_for_valid_images(children[i]);
        }
    },

    get_image_array: function()
    {
        return Object.keys(this.image_array)
    }
}

imageSearch.scan_for_valid_images(document);
imageSearch.get_image_array()
```

Try copy-pasting that into the console of this window to see it in action.

Comment: cool+useful code snippet, but the `valid_image_nodes` seems rather arbitrary. Really, there can be an image on *any* element, so why not just avoid that whole `if (this.valid_image_nodes...` condition?

Comment: Sorry, I was using this for a personal project. You are right, you should include any element by removing that condition.

Answer (score 1):

You can count with CSS using the `counter-reset` and `counter-increment` and count items with CSS.

```css
body {
  counter-reset: img;
}

img {
  counter-increment: img;
  content:counter(img);
  content:"";
}

div.main:after {
  content: "Images Counted: " counter(img);
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
</div>
```

However to count all the items you want you could do:

```css
body {
  counter-reset: count;
}

img {
  counter-increment: count;
  content:counter(count);
  content:"";
}

p:before {
  counter-increment: count;
  content:counter(count);
  content:"";
}

h1:before {
  counter-increment: count;
  content:counter(count);
  content:"";
}

div.main:after {
  content: "Items Counted: " counter(count);
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
  <p> This paragraph is also counted </p>
  <h1> This header 1 is also counted </h1>
</div>
```

You could also place this information in a hidden `div` and extract it later, if needed.

Here is something for reference: http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/05/learn-to-count-with-css/

Comment: thank you for the awesome and fascinating answer. I had no idea I could do that with CSS. I suppose I could use some clever *attribute contains* css magic to get elements with inline-images etc. However, while this does look useful, I'm looking for a JS solution.

Comment: @ZachL oh you commented on another answer asking for just Css I must have misunderstood.

Comment: Oh I see where that might be confusing. When I said "check for images in CSS" I meant check for images applied via css. Like `p {background: url(foo.png); }`

Comment: @ZachL Gotcha!  Without adding anything else like a class.  Ok.  So any element that has that background you want to count?  or any background at all?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following at the bottom of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var imgCount = document.images.length;
    var svgCount = document.getElementsByTagName('svg').length;
    var finalCount = imgCount + svgCount;
</script>
```

Comment: but no simple way to check for images in CSS huh?

Answer (score 0):

with jquery you can use something like this for counter backgroundImage

```
var ctBkImg = 0;
$("*").each(function(){
    if ($(this).css("background-image") != "none" ) ctBkImg++
});
```

Comment: thank you for this, but really not looking for a bunch of answers with approaches for querying individual types of images that can appear on the page. I'm capable of doing, (or looking up) all these things individually. Good answers would have a catch-all approach, explain that such an approach is not possible, or possibly list all the different types of images that can be found and explain that those need to be combined.